# При нажатии на кнопки, функции работают, но программное управление выводит код из строя

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Использую **Visual Studio 2019**

Программа определения QR кода с веб камеры.
 Определяет любой QR код, а при обнаружении определенного QR кода, нужно выполнить действие. 
Она работает, но.....

Столкнулся с неясной мне проблемой.

Есть форма. На ней: PictureBox (**pbWebCamPrev**), TextBox (**tbText**), две кнопки (**btnStart**) и (**button1**), ListBox (**lbCams**).

Кнопка Старт (**btnStart**) запускает трансляцию в PictureBox (**pbWebCamPrev**) и определение QR кода.

Кнопка Стоп (**button1**) прекращает трансляцию.

Если нажимать на кнопки мышью, то трансляция спокойно запускается и останавливается.

Но если задать автоматическое действие при определенном тексте в TextBox (**tbText**), то после остановки трансляции, запуск уже не производится даже с кнопки (только перезапуск программы).

Как с этим бороться и что можно сделать?

```
...
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using ZXing;

namespace Сканер_QR
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;
    private ZXing.BarcodeReader reader;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    delegate void SetStringDelegate(String parametr);

    void SetResult(string result)
    {
        if (!InvokeRequired)
            tbText.Text = result;
        else
            Invoke(new SetStringDelegate(SetResult), new object[] { result });
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        reader = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();
        reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>();
        reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);


        if (videoDevices.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (FilterInfo device in videoDevices)
            {
                lbCams.Items.Add(device.Name);
            }
            lbCams.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start();
    }

    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

        pbWedCamPrev.Image = bitmap;

        ZXing.Result result = reader.Decode((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone());
        if (result != null)
        {
            SetResult(result.Text);
            read();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoSource != null)
        {
            videoSource.SignalToStop();
            videoSource.WaitForStop();
        }
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stop();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[lbCams.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        videoSource.Start();
    }
    void Stop()
    {
        videoSource.Stop();
        videoSource.SignalToStop();
        videoSource.WaitForStop();

    }
    void read()
    {
        if (tbText.Text == "Нужный текст")
        {
            Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("True"); // Месседж  для примера, по идее тут выполнение другого кода
            Start();
        }
    }        
}
}
```

Пробовал использовать код без `Stop()` и `Start()`

```
void read()
{
    if (tbText.Text == "Нужный текст")
    {              
        MessageBox.Show("True"); // Месседж  для примера, по идее тут выполнение другого кода             
    }
}
```

В этом случае сообщение появляется, трансляция "якобы" останавливается, и даже выполняется действие (при испытаниях запуска функций, а не месседжа),
 но это дело повторяется довольно большое количество раз. В зависимости от того, сколько QR код был перед камерой. Если секунду, то раз 8. Если дольше то и 10 и 20 раз.

Comment: Попробуйте костылик: в методе `read` после вызова `Stop();` поставьте `Application.DoEvents()`. Поможет?

Comment: ' if (tbText.Text == "Нужный текст")
            {
                Stop();
                Application.DoEvents();
                MessageBox.Show("True"); // Месседж  для примера, по идее тут выполнение другого кода
                Start();

            }'   ничего не изменилось

Comment: Вообще, как я понял, нужно найти способ обнулить написанное в TextBox

Comment: Для начала откажитесь от идеи хранить данные в ГУИ.  Заведите поле `string currResult;`  и в `SetResult()` сохраняйте сначала в него, а потом уже в textBox. В `read()` соответственно читайте из поля, а не с ГУИ.
И поменяйте `Invoke()` на `BeginInvoke()`.
Ну а уже потом, надо задуматься о выполнении рабочего кода отдельно от ГУИ-потока, разделении на разные классы, и может даже о буферизации отсылаемых на интерфейс данных.